# DRYing out some Java code and tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, inheritance

I am writing some tests that all follow the same pattern, I feel like repeating myself over and over again, how can I reduce the repetition? The (almost) repeating part is in constructor and the class level variables:

**`VariablesPage`**

```
public class VariablesPage extends LoadableComponent<VariablesPage> {

    private final TestHelpers helpers;
    private WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[@title=\"Define new variable\"]") 
    private WebElement btnAddNewVariable;

    public VariablesPage() throws Exception {
        helpers = new TestHelpers();
        driver = helpers.getWebDriver();
        helpers.setHar(VariablesPage.class.getSimpleName());
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        isLoaded();
        helpers.getHar();
    }

    @Override
    protected void load() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void isLoaded() throws Error {
        helpers.waitUntil(btnAddNewVariable);
    }
}
```

**`addStepsPage`**

```
public class AddStepsPage extends LoadableComponent<AddStepsPage> {

    private final TestHelpers helpers;
    private WebDriver driver;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class=\"body sequential\"]")
    private WebElement divStepsBody;

    public AddStepsPage() throws Exception {
        helpers = new TestHelpers();
        driver = helpers.getWebDriver();
        helpers.setHar(AddStepsPage.class.getSimpleName());
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        isLoaded();
        helpers.getHar();
    }


    @Override
    protected void load() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void isLoaded() throws Error {
        helpers.waitUntil(divStepsBody);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, let us collect the code pieces which are repeated

**Fields**

> ```
> private final TestHelpers helpers;
> private WebDriver driver;
> ```

**Constructor related**

> ```
> helpers = new TestHelpers();  
> driver = helpers.getWebDriver();
> ```

Now, let's start refactoring by extending `LoadableComponent<T>`

```
public abstract class ExtendedLoadableComponent<T> extends LoadableComponent<T> {

    protected final TestHelpers helpers
    protected WebDriver driver;

    public ExtendedLoadableComponent() throws Exception {
        helpers = new TestHelpers();
        driver = helpers.getWebDriver();
    }
}
```

which reduces the first class to

```
public class VariablesPage extends ExtendedLoadableComponent<VariablesPage> {

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[@title=\"Define new variable\"]") 
    private WebElement btnAddNewVariable;

    public VariablesPage() throws Exception {
        super();
        helpers.setHar(VariablesPage.class.getSimpleName());
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        isLoaded();
        helpers.getHar();
    }

    @Override
    protected void load() {}

    @Override
    protected void isLoaded() throws Error {
        helpers.waitUntil(btnAddNewVariable);
    }
}
```

But wait, we can do better! So, let us also call `helpers.setHar(String)` and thus we need to refactor the constructor of `ExtendedLoadableComponent<T>`

```
public abstract class ExtendedLoadableComponent<T> extends LoadableComponent<T> {

    protected final TestHelpers helpers
    protected WebDriver driver;

    public ExtendedLoadableComponent(Class<T> pageClassToProxy) throws Exception {
        helpers = new TestHelpers();
        driver = helpers.getWebDriver();
        helpers.setHar(pageClassToProxy.getSimpleName());
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, pageClassToProxy);
    }
}
```

which reduces the first class to

```
public class VariablesPage extends ExtendedLoadableComponent<VariablesPage> {

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[@title=\"Define new variable\"]") 
    private WebElement btnAddNewVariable;

    public VariablesPage() throws Exception {
        super(VariablesPage.class);
        isLoaded();
        helpers.getHar();
    }

    @Override
    protected void load() {}

    @Override
    protected void isLoaded() throws Error {
        helpers.waitUntil(btnAddNewVariable);
    }
}
```

**Naming**

I don't know if the `TestHelpers` class is your own. If yes, you should think about changing the names for `setHar()` and `getHar()` so Mr. Maintainer can evaluate what they do by looking at the names.

Comment: har is referring to [HTTP archive format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.har) which contains performance metrics, HTTP statuses etc. It is commented in TestHelpers class : ). And thanks for a great answer!

Comment: @erki-m If you need a comment to explain the method, then its name is bad.

Comment: @Kolargol00 point taken.

Answer (score 6):

First off, testing is inherently repeated. You are exploring many facets of the same attribute of your program, which means doing many things in slightly different ways.

Your job is to control the repeating so you aren't overwhelming yourself or costing too much money. You use the software design tools for testing that help you in the basic code.

**Test Harness**

As Eugene T pointed out, `@Before` and `@After` methods are available in the test harness, whether it is JUnit or TestNG. These methods might be configured to run before/after each method, class, test or suite.

**Inheritance**

In your example, you could create a common base class and then override the definition of some variables in the constructor.

**Composition**

You can create separate components that handle common elements and your test class composes them. Your test methods then invoke the methods on the components that are needed.

**Further Research**

This is just the start of a list of tools that you have at your disposal. You have the internet at your disposal for doing your own research on refactoring.

Answer (score 5):

Just a few additional remarks on top of [@heslacher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/29371/heslacher)'s excellent review.

Don't throw `Exception`. If one of those methods inside the function throw some kind of Exception, then use that, don't fall back to the `Exception` parent class. You should always use the most specific `Exception` classes possible.

Definitely don't throw `Error`. `Error` is neither something to throw nor something to try to catch. Don't use it. See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) for more details.

Finally, if you don't need to override a method, then don't override it:

> ```
> @Override
> protected void load() {}
> ```

If you must override it with an empty body, for example to prevent the method in the parent class from doing something, then add a comment to explain why this method needs to be there.